# Result from API call made in saga is null

Tags: redux-saga

I have a Redux Saga that calls an API endpoint (GET) via a custom library that returns a promise encompassing a `request.get`using the Superagent library. When I make this request in my React app, Chrome dev tools shows the request being made correctly, and the response, however the `response` object in the saga is null after this GET is made. I have seen similar questions on StackOverflow, where the solution ("solution") was to have the saga call a new function that then calls the API endpoint. This did not solve my issue.

```
function* exportFile({ payload }) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(getFile, payload);
        console.log(response); // null

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


export function getFile(data) {
    return ajaxClient.get({
        url: '/api/getFile',
        data
    });
}
```

Payload is sent correctly in the GET, the backend receives the parameters and sends the correct response. Since Chrome dev tools is showing the request and response correctly, I believe the issue has to do with the Saga not waiting for the response to come back as the response of `null` is logged to the console before Chrome dev tools shows the response in the Network tab.

Comment: What is logged if you do `getFile(payload).then(response => console.log(response))`?

Comment: sure enough, it is also null. I thought for sure it would return the string of the response. So this indicates an issue with the proxy call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with Redux Saga, it was an issue with the ajaxClient library which expects JSON rather than a file or a string.